# Unable to attach bones to 3D model or create vertex groups

Tags: bones

I have created a creature for the project and I am supposed to create an animation where the creature is running. This is where my problem comes in, I cannot get the bones used on my creature to attach or create vertex groups for the individual parts. If you could reply with directions or instructions as soon as possible that’d be lovely. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what steps have you already tried and at what step does it not do what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried linking your model to the rig using automatic weights? (i.e. By selecting your model first and then your rig, then pressing control+P, and then choosing: With Automatic Weights)
You could then vertex paint the weight of each bone individually by hand to your liking.